# Simple formatting of astropy Tables ascii output

Tags: python, astropy

I have three variables, wavelength, flux and err_flux which are all type astropy.table.table.Table. I've combined them into one variable, output as such:

```
output = Table([wavelength,flux,err_flux], names=['wavelength', 'flux', 'err_flux']))
```

However, when I now look at `output', I get the single entries having ( and ,) formatting and being type numpy.voids

```
In [1]: output                                                                                                                                                                
Out[1]: 
<Table length=5384>
  wavelength         flux         err_flux   
     void64          void64         void64    
----------------- -------------- --------------
(3199.30539694,)  (9.04838805,)  (0.90483881,)
(3200.35733828,)  (7.50614256,)  (0.75061426,)
(3201.40933772,)  (6.93674224,)  (0.69367422,)
....
```

What's going on, and how can I just have three floats per line here?

Comment: FYI the [datatables] tag refers to the jQuery DataTables plugin, I was assuming you're not talking about that and probably mean [pandas] instead.

Comment: This question is unrelated to pandas.

Comment: This question seems to be unrelated to its ascii tag

Answer (score 1):

> I have three variables, wavelength, flux and err_flux which are all type astropy.table.table.Table.

Having each of those three variables starting as a single-column table is a little strange, so backing up one step and understanding why these data columns are `Table` objects is one place to start.

But if you really have these three data tables, you can use the `astropy.table.hstack` function to stack them horizontally into a single table:

```
from astropy.table import hstack
output = hstack([wavelength, flux, err_flux])
```

You could also pull out the first column from each table:

```
output = Table([wavelength.columns[0], flux.columns[0], err_flux.columns[0]],
               names=['wavelength', 'flux', 'err_flux'])
```

FYI, what's going on?  An astropy Table column can be a Table!

```
In [45]: t = simple_table()

In [46]: t2 = Table([t, t])

In [47]: t2
Out[47]: 
<Table length=3>
     col0          col1    
   void160       void160   
------------- -------------
(1,  1., 'c') (1,  1., 'c')
(2,  2., 'd') (2,  2., 'd')
(3,  3., 'e') (3,  3., 'e')
```